scikit-mobility: save map to a png file
I am using the scikit-mobility library to plot gps trajectory in a Jupyter notebook.
#pip -q install scikit-mobility

import skmob

# file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scikit-mobility/scikit-mobility/master/examples/geolife_sample.txt.gz
tdf = skmob.TrajDataFrame.from_file('geolife_sample.txt.gz', latitude='lat', 
                  longitude='lon', user_id='user', datetime='datetime')
# print a portion of the TrajDataFrame
print(tdf.head())

         lat         lng            datetime  uid
0  39.984094  116.319236 2008-10-23 05:53:05    1
1  39.984198  116.319322 2008-10-23 05:53:06    1
2  39.984224  116.319402 2008-10-23 05:53:11    1
3  39.984211  116.319389 2008-10-23 05:53:16    1
4  39.984217  116.319422 2008-10-23 05:53:21    1

tdf.plot_trajectory(zoom=12, weight=3, opacity=0.9, tiles='Stamen Toner')


This is an interactive map plot in browser. In my case, it is intended for manuscript, ideally in png (or pdf) for publication quality.
Any workaround that?
